# Ubuntu LUKS fails to boot after installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, boot-loader, refind

1. Unplug HDD
2. Plug an empty USB drive
3. Plug Ubuntu 21 live USB
4. Install Ubuntu 21 on the empty USB drive (LUKS enabled)
5. Unplug Ubuntu 21 live USB
6. Use the new live ubuntu with persistence and encryption enabled

Everything works fine until I plug back the main HDD.
Now the Ubuntu with LUKS enabled will not boot with error

`mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory`

I suspect that the bootloader is not reading the correct disk because now my main HDD as taken the /dev/sda slot

Any idea on how to fix the bootloader?
I'm using refind and I tried to pass options such as root=/dev/sdb3 and rootdelay=10